# Redirecting iframes based on the result of an Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a set of web pages consisting of the following:

```
template20_L.php <Parent>
template20_1_L_iframe.php <iframe 1>
template20_override_L.php <iframe 2>
template20_signage_L.php <iframe 3>
```

The parent page loads and loads `iframe 1` as the default.

Inside "iframe 1" I have a script that checks for any changes in an underlying data table.

Check script: check.php

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "Post",
  url: "check_override.php",
  success: function(data) {
  var result = $.parseJSON(data);
  if(result == 1) {
    console.log("REDIRECT OVERRIDE = 1");
    $(function(){
      $(".container", window.top.document).hide();
    });
    window.location.href = 'template20_override_L.php';
  } else if(result == 2) {
    console.log("REDIRECT SIGNAGEE = 2");
    $(function(){
      $(".container", window.top.document).hide();
    });
    window.location.href = 'template20_signage_L.php';
  } else  {
    console.log("NO REDIRECT = 3");
    $(function(){
      $(".container", window.top.document).show();
    });
    window.location.href = 'template20_1_L_iframe.php';
  }
  }
  });
}, 9000);
```

The "check.php" script runs two mysqli queries the first checks for the value of a column named `FullDb`. If `FullDb == 1`
load `iframe 2`. If `fullDb` is empty then check a different table find if there are any records that match the query.
If the second query returns any record then load `iframe 3`.

The Check.php script:

```
//Run the first query
if($rowcount > 0 ) {
    $y = 1;
    echo $y;
} elseif($rowcount == 0 ) {
// run the second query
  $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);   
  if($rowcount > 0 ) {
    $y = 2;
    echo $y;    
  } else {
    echo $y = 0;
  }
}
```

If the ajax result == 1 then load "iframe 2", elseif the result == 2 then load "iframe 3, else do nothing.

The issue I am having is if the result == 1, "iframe 2" loads but if the result condition changes and the result is empty I need "iframe 1" to reload. The console is showing that although the condition has change, i.e an empty result, "iframe 2" is still active in stead of displaying "iframe".

My question is how can I get this to work or a I going about this completely wrong.

Comment: The use of iframes in such a scenario feels pretty wrong-ish already. What is their actual purpose - do you have to display results from a different system that is out of your control in them, or anything like that? _“Inside "iframe 1" I have a script that checks for any changes in an underlying data table.”_ - that checking should probably not need an iframe, if you are using AJAX already.

Comment: @04FS Hi and thanks for your reply. The scenario is, the parent and the default iframe "iframe 1" load display rows of data. The user has the option to override this by way of making a selection in the user interface control panel for the site. If the user selects the override option then basically hide/remove "iframe 1" and replace it with "iframe 2" which displays a full screen image. "iframe 2" remains displayed until the underlying query returns no records, If no record are found then load  "iframe 1" again  and display.

Comment: Even without AJAX, it isn't clear why you need iframe to accomplish your desired behavior. You can even use the same webmethod and call it with your switch/parameter from the ajax success handler. In this case the webmethod returns either rows of data or the full screen image. What purpose does the iframe serve to this end? I don't see it.

Comment: @mjw Hi, I am currently revisiting the structure of the script to try and remove the iframe sections. Once I have I will post what I have done to resolve the issue. Many thanks for looking at the question.